# identical postgresql query with different performance

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with measurement data containing the data, a connected_id (the sensor) and a timestamp. I'm searching this table for the first timestamp of a specific sensor. For some sensors I get a result in 2ms, other sensors take a couple of seconds to finish. Also, when I remove the where conditions searching for a specific sensor, the result is within ms.

[image: screen shot with <code>EXPLAIN ANALYZE</code> output]

Both queries use the same plan, are executed on the same server using postgresql 8.4. I've already done a vacuum analyze on the database and played around with the query plan in the postgresql.conf file.

I've tried both btree and hash indexes on created, connected_id and both of these columns. This doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Don't screenshot text, but instead paste it here, as text.

Comment: How is the index `data_index` defined?

Comment: it also depends on the volume of data. what's the `count(*)` returns for both sets of condition?

Comment: @donkopotamus The data_index was defined as btree(created)

Comment: @Rahul the number of records is shown in the explain. connected_id 26 has 3M results and connected_id 19 has 5M results. The total table contains about 50M results

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

The query plan chosen searches through an index ordered by `created` in ascending order and stops when it finds the first row with matching `connected_id`.

Now there are rows with `connected_id = 19` with low `created`, so a match is quickly found.

But obviously all rows with `connected_id = 26` have rather high `created`, so the query has to scan many index entries before a match is found.

That explains the difference.
If you used a more recent, less unsupported, version of PostgreSQL, more diagnostics could be used to show what is going on, like `EXPLAIN (BUFFERS)`.

I would create a multicolumn index on `(connected_id, created)` to speed up this query.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I have tried a multicolumn index on `(created, connected_id)`. First ordering on connected_id would make sense. Will try and let you know the result.